# How to extract from the second last value

Tags: javascript, string

From the following URL example:

google.com/sports/football/asia

How to extract from the second last forward slash, that is /football/asia using jQuery? I know the functions are substring and lastIndexOf(), but how to use them in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not jQuery at all. You're talking about plain vanilla out-of-the-browser Javascript here.

Comment: Tell me more about it! This JavaScript jQuery difference will remain a mystery to me. Thanks everyone for their help and comments.

Comment: Haha. :D Well, as a rule of thumb, jQuery is a Javascript library. there's nothing you can do in jQuery that you can't do with Javascript --- it's just there to help make things easier for you. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant *RegEx*? The correct regex for that would be: `/\w+\/\w+$/i`. You can use Javascript's [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to get your content from the string:

```
var myContent = "google.com/sports/football/asia".match(/\w+\/\w+$/i);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var url = "google.com/sports/football/asia";
var arr = url.split('/'),
foo = arr[arr.length-2] + '/' + arr[arr.length-1];
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`String.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) function -- twice:

```
var str = "google.com/sports/football/asia";
var foo = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/", str.lastIndexOf("/") - 1));
```

A better solution would be to use the [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function followed by [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) functions 1like so:

```
"google.com/sports/football/asia".split("/").slice(-2).join("/");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function and take the last 2 elements of the resulting array:

```
var url = 'google.com/sports/football/asia';
var parts = url.split('/');
if (parts.length > 1) {
    var result = parts[parts.length - 2] + '/' + parts[parts.length - 1];
    alert(result);
}
```

​